# What is the name of the current position when you sit cross-legged on the floor and then extend one of your legs?

Tags: yoga

This position is called cross-legged :

[image]

What's the name of the position of the legs in these images?

Bending forward or to the side is not what I'm asking.

I found this name: "Janu Sirsasana," but I don't think this describes just the position of the legs.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Cross-legged posture called swastikasana. Main difference between Swastikasana and Padmasana is, in Swastikasana, foot will be on the ground(ie. outer edge of your foot). and in Padmasana, foot will be on your thighs.
When you keep one leg straight and other leg folded, then that can be called as ardha swastikasana.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your context, this pose is a half straddle. Straddle splits are with both legs spread outward, a half straddle is with one leg tucked in. The above pose in [Yin yoga is called Dragonfly](https://www.bodywindow.com/half-dragonfly-pose.html), and the half straddle is called a half dragonfly.

This may have other names in other variations of yoga.

[image]